# SEBLOD. Joomla menu link to particular article

Tags: joomla

How I can create menu link to particular article with SEBLOD? When you create menu item to SEBLOD there are 2 options: form, list & search type.

Of course I can create search with parameter art_id and get the article I need. But the problem is that article may contain form. And it's impossible, because SEBLOD wraps whole page with its own form if you use list & search type.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by myself.
You can just **create menu link to single Joomla article**. If this article is one of SEBLOD items in this case  SEBLOD by means of its plugins will process this item, no metter that menu link is not one of SEBLOD's entities. Also it will use its own template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. SEBLOD is smoothly integrated with Joomla. Any view of Joomla can be used to display SEBLOD items such as article view, and other list views such as category list view or category blog view.
But for "list views" the best performance is with native SEBLOD view by using list & search SEBLOD views.
Regards.